# Running a python script before executing the current script

Tags: python, import

I have two scripts `txt_generator.py` and `driver.py`  in the same directory

For a successful run,

1. First `txt_generator.py` is run and it writes some info to a `.txt` file.
2. The info from the `.txt` file is then used by `driver.py`  for a few tasks.

I am currently trying to run `txt_generator.py` from within `driver.py`  to eliminate the first step but I am unable to do so.

I have tried calling it from `driver.py`  using

```
import txt_generator

# Some tasks

if __name__ == '__main__':
   txt_generator.main()
```

and

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["python", r"/Users/arun/Downloads/Project/txt_generator.py", "-i", "10", "-l", "2"])
```

which throws a
`ImportError: No module named` error

I have also tried other methods but `.txt` file never gets written

Please Advise.

Comment: `import driver` ?

Comment: import driver ? Meaning?

Comment: from `txt_generator.py` file, import `driver` module and from module run the functions that you want

Comment: `import txt_generator` is executed successfully? I do not see any problems with your approach. How are sou starting `driver.py`? Perhaps it is not started in the directory containing the two python scripts? Try adding `import os;
print os.getcwd()` in `driver.py`

Comment: it looks like `text_generator.py` needs you to provide some CLI arguments (based on what you show in second snippet). When you import it and then try to run `main()` you don't supply any arguments. Also what happens when you try to import and call `main()`?

Comment: @confiq why would he import `driver` if that is the starting script?

Comment: @sivic When I run  `text_generator.py` first from Mac's Terminal and then run `driver.py` from Mac's Terminal it works perfectly fine the issues arise when I'm trying to automate the process

Comment: @buran When `main()` is called `driver.py` throws an error since the `.txt` file is empty

Comment: So, you need to examine the `text_generator.py` if it is not written by you and see how it use the CLI arguments. Probably it pass them (to `main`?). Unless you show us the code in `text_generator.py` I don't think we can be of more help.

Comment: @buran How do I show you the code? `text_generator.py` has about 100 lines of code